# Python Codes For Solving And Plotting 1st Order Differential Equations

Tags: python, plot, derivative

I am stuck in trouble here with a python homework of mine. I am asked to write a python code that solve this differential equation:

```
R*C* dUc(t)/dt+Uc(t)-Vdc = 0
```

and then determine `i(t)` and `UR(t)` where `i(t)=C* dUc(t)/dt`, `UR(t) =i(t)*R`, and `R`,`Vdc`,`C` are constants. Related to diff equations all that we were teached is Sympy tools package. I have written this code:

```
from sympy import *
Vdc=int(input(" Please enter the value of Vdc:"))
R=int(input(" Please enter the value of R:"))
C=int(input("Please enter the value of C:"))
t=Symbol("t") 
Uc=Function("Uc") 
i=Function("i") 
i=C*(Derivative(Uc(t),t))
UR=Function("UR")
UR=i*R
dequation=Eq(R*i+Uc(t)-Vdc)
print(dsolve(dequation,Uc(t)))
```

But unfortunately this does not help me at all,since when I run the program the solution of the equation comes out in the form of `Eq(Uc(t),.......)` which seems nonsense to me, because how I am supposed to control/edit or make any thing with such an answer... I can not make an equality for `Uc(t)` and I can not take its derivatives... etc. 
Help PLEASE!

Comment: Consult [this](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/solvers.html#solving-differential-equations) page. There are good example how to solve differential equations. Your code is valid, you just obtained a wrong answer.

Comment: Sorry, you even get a right answer `Uc(t) == exp(C1 - t/6) + 5`, when I execute your code with Python 2.7, so I can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I think it is wrong to write this code: Uc(t) == exp(C1 - t/6) + 5 since the order dsolve() gives the result as an equation which I am not able to do anything with it, I mean I can not make it corresponds to Uc(t) , I can not take its derivatives, and I am not able to plot the asked graphs too..

Comment: This is what I am asked to do, tomorrow is the deadline..could anyone help please.. http://www.pdf-archive.com/2016/05/12/elk107ehw3/

Comment: You can access to expression obtained as a solution this way: `solution = dsolve(dequation,Uc(t)).args[1]`.